# How To Export Project from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

How do you export a a project from Android Studio? I have a project for school and we're supposed to export our projects, but no one in my class has any idea how, and neither does the TA.

Comment: Um, there really isn't an "export". The project is just a directory of files. You would have to ask whoever is telling you that you're "supposed to export [your] projects" what they mean.

Answer (score 1):

> If you want to build Signed APK, there are few simple steps to follow

1. Click on Build menu -> Generate Signed Bundle / APK...

[image]

2. Select APK option and Click on the Next button

[image]

3. Click on the Create new... button

[image]

4. Click on the key store path's folder icon

[image]

5. Select any destination folder, type a File name and press the OK button

[image]

6. Fill up the form and press the OK button. `(** When you filling up the form avoid special characters such as + , etc)`

[image]

7. Press the Next button

[image]

8. Choose Destination path, select release, put the checkmark on V1, V2 and click on Finish

[image]

When the APK successfully generated, click on the locate button to show your apk file   :) That's it...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just press **Build** > **Make Project**. You will find the apk in **app/build/apk/** in your project's folder

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just get the apk for your android project, then Build > Make Project then you can get the apk in app/build/apk/ in your project's folder.

However, if you want to say use the project source code onto another, say your school computer from your home computer, just copy and paste your entire project folder and then open the same project folder from the other computer.

If you want to export the Android studio project to be opened in say another IDE like Eclipse, you cannot import the project directly but it's not to hard to achieve it:

Create a new Android empty project in eclipse
Overwrite the fresh res/ folder and the AndroidManifest.xml file, with the ones from the Android Studio project
Copy the content of the java/ folder from the Android Studio project (it should contain your package name folder structure, like com/example/app/, and the java files of course) in the Eclipse src folder
Link your needed libraries if it's the case
Basically the Android application fundamental elements are the java files, the manifest file and the resources. From there you can build back a project in your favorite IDE.